# How to show row positional change without a macro

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I’d like to know how to show the positional change of data in a table based on the row without using a macro. This is a theoretical question so I don’t have a demo file to share.

Imagine a 3 column (A:C) table sorted by C:C which automatically updates when new data is added via a Google Form. Is it possible in a new column (D:D) to demonstrate the positional change of each row entry based on its previous position?

E.g. if data from row 2 moves to row 4, D4 will = “-2” or if data from row 20 moves to row 10, D10 will = “+10”.

In case it makes a difference, the values in A:A will be unique text. B:C will be calculated numbers.

Comment: Hi ajw136.  Two questions: since responses from Forms typically get added sequentially to a "Responses" sheet, the sheet you are talking about here would be a different sheet/tab from the Responses sheet, correct?  And it is getting the form response data with perhaps a query or importrange?  I'm sure this could be done with a script solution, but which you are excluding.  So the only formula approach I can imagine would involve analysing the row position of a data item if sorting the responses range EXCLUDING the last entry in the responses, vs the row position after the latest sort.  Follow?

Comment: Thanks. This does make sense. I’ve realised I need to create two tables of data - one full and one excluding the last entry and then subtract the Match results for each entry. My only problem is that I have so many additional steps and calculation tabs between the entries and the form I want to show positional change. I’ll just have to think of a way of streamlining those steps.

Comment: So are the forms submitting updated information about an existing data record (a team, person, company, stock, etc) or adding entirely new data values?  If the latter, it would seem relatively straightforward, regardless of intermediate steps, to just "exclude" the latest data record to do that positional comparison, right?  But if the forms are providing updates, then I can see the challenge - not sure how you could "ignore" the last update...

Comment: Here is a link to a copy of the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1avakZR2_VtBhAz51CsKLzKa9giCM2q4StL_LreqyIO8/edit?usp=sharing The data is entered in 'Form Responses 1' and then goes through a number of calculation tabs before appearing as I want to view it in 'Book League'!A:D. The positional change icons would ideally be in or next to 'Book League'!A:D. I hope this makes things clearer. Aside from duplicating all calculation tabs but excluding the last row of data and then comparing, I don't know if this will be possible, and the sheet is getting slow as it is!

Comment: Impressive work!  I followed your ranking logic through the sheets, and I think I might be able to do it.  It may take me a week or so, but will let you know if I succeed or give up...

Comment: Thanks very much. This is not important - in fact it's a nice-to-have. As you can probably see from the scruffy nature of my work, this started as a bit of a lockdown hobby and has evolved into a bit of a monster! This particular task is a case of man vs machine, but I'm quite happy to concede to machine in this instance!

Comment: I gave it some effort, but I've decided my brain can't handle trying to follow the analysis steps to do this the way I was thinking.  But I've just thought of another approach, that might be quite simple, with a bit of code.  Develop/record a macro that saves the top 100 book titles and and their current ranking, perhaps with the current datetime.  Then submit the new form.  Then run the macro again to have a new set of columns.  Now it should be easy to compare where each book is in those two sets of columns.  Or maybe do this once a day, to see the changes per day.  Make any sense?

Comment: You could keep a tab that has book titles in A, then two columns per date, their ranking on that date, and their delta up or down from the previous date.  Whether that is after every new form, or once a day or once a week, whatever frequency you want...  Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this makes sense. I'll have a go at creating that and see what I can come up with. Thanks for your help!